# Execute a function before viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, api, uiviewcontroller

This view is going to present a set of questions. These questions will be read from an api. I have 2 ways either to load them in the last view or load them in the current view but before the viewDidLoad method. I tried the viewWillAppear but didn't work well. How can I do that?

**Edit:**

This is the function that reads the data from the api:

```
func readData(id: String, userCompletionHandler: @escaping ([String], Error?) -> Void){
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://adminsapi.somee.com/Api/Test/?id=\(id)")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"

            var questionArr = [String]()
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                if response != nil {
                    //print("Response: \(response!)")
                }
                if let data = data {
                    do{
                        self.questionObject = try JSONDecoder().decode([Questions].self, from: data)
                        for question in self.questionObject{
                            questionArr.append(question.question)
                        }
                        userCompletionHandler(questionArr, nil)
                    } catch{
                        print("Error in retrieving data: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                else{
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
                })
            dataTask.resume()
        }
```

and this is the where I navigate to the next View Controller:

```
func moveToNextVC(finalString: String){
        let VC1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuestionsTableViewController") as? QuestionsTableViewController
        if finalString.lowercased().contains("abdominal distention"){
            readData(id: "1", userCompletionHandler: { data, error in
                VC1?.questions = data
            })
            self.present(VC1!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

> The problem is when I print the questions array in "QuestionsTableViewController" it is always empty

Comment: you have to do in the last view, you can't load nothing before viewDidLoad begins. please read this (https://medium.com/good-morning-swift/ios-view-controller-life-cycle-2a0f02e74ff5)

Comment: Maybe it's better to call loading function in viewDidLoad asynchronously, show some loader indicator and then update the presenting view?

Comment: I updated the question please check it

Comment: When are you calling `tableView.reloadData()` ?

Comment: @koen I don't need the data in the current view so I don't call the tableview.reloadData(), my problem is that the data isn't passed to the second view controller

Comment: My guess is `self.present(VC1!, animated: true, completion: nil)` is called before `readData()` is finished.

Comment: @koen I made an if condition to never execute the self.present(VC1!, animated: true, completion: nil) if questions.count == 0 and it never move to the next view controller

Comment: Well if `questions.count == 0` then there is an issue with your `readData()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order from left to right

> loadView -> viewDidLoad -> viewWillAppear

there is no much time enough to do this either in `loadView` , you need to load the api in the previous vc then show the needed 1 , or make the call inside `viewDidLoad`